# Highlight Ruby methods and method parameters in different colors in an editor

Tags: ruby, editor, sublimetext2, syntax-highlighting

Is there any editor with any color scheme in which:

```
BulkMailer.bulk_email recipient, body
```

`bulk_email` is highlighted in one color and the parameters are highlighted in a different color. I use Sublime Text 2 and I tried a lot of color schemes but so far none of them does that.

While this works when defining methods (here `bulk_email` has a different color):

```
def bulk_email(recipient, body)
  # some logic
end
```

I would like to have that also in method calls. I find this especially helpful, as Ruby allows for omitting the braces around parameter lists and in long lists it's sometimes a little slow to detect where the actual method call ends. As I mentioned, I don't insist on Sublime, any editor is fine.

Comment: Brackets are optional, but there's nothing to say you can't use them religiously so that your editor can properly highlight things.

Comment: Well that's the thing. First off, even with brackets method name and params and colored the same (in method calls). Secondly, I need this feature much more when reading other people's code.

Comment: You could try hacking around with the syntax highlighter rules, but these are not always easy to get right. Since Ruby has such a loose syntax it's often very hard for the parser to identify what an argument is.

Comment: I updated my answer for sublime text although I like `SynWrite`s easier usage. Please note the caveats in my answer. They can be overcome with a more complex expression but as a proof of concept I think this shows what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SynWrite** editor (Windows) can do it.

Activate Ruby lexer, goto lexer properties dialog, create new Parser called ".name" to hilite names after a dot with a new color, and set parser's regex.
Result with hilited method name (with my changes in lexer):
[image: Ruby test]

Answer (score 0):

Here you go solution for Sublime Text 2

**Ruby.tmLanguage** (Add)

```
<dict>
    <key>captures</key>
    <dict>
        <key>1</key>
        <dict>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>entity.chained.name.function.ruby</string>
        </dict>
        <key>2</key>
        <dict>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>variable.chained.parameter.function.ruby</string>
        </dict>
        <key>3</key>
        <dict>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>comment</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>match</key>
    <string>^.*\.(\w+)(.*?)(#.*)*?$</string>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>meta.function.method.with-arguments.ruby</string>
</dict>
```

**In your Theme File (default is Monokai.thTheme)** (Add)

```
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Function name</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>entity.chained.name.function</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>foreground</key>
        <string>PUT A HEX COLOR VALUE HERE</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Function argument</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>variable.chained.parameter</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>fontStyle</key>
        <string>italic</string>
        <key>foreground</key>
        <string>PUT A HEX COLOR VALUE HERE</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

this will cause the method name to be one color and the argumetns to be another and inline comments to match as comments.

**Huge Caveats**
This was fun but I don't really feel like exploring further so here are some caveats that could be overcome with a much more complex regex. Highlights the following additional items that are probably not intended by your question.

1.Final Chain Methods Ending in alpha_numeric characters
  2.Inline blocks with a space between called method and block
  3.Multiline Block keywords and piped variables

Comment: unfortunately, this does not solve the OP's problem - those are not instance variables in his code.

Comment: @MattDMo Yes I am well aware. As is stated in my answer but I wanted to at least show him how this type of thing could be implemented all he needs is an appropriate set of regex's in the tmLanguage file to implement I was hoping Sublime had built on in but I have yet to find it.